# Как получить JSON-файл на стороне сервера

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Пытаюсь получить json-файл и распарсить его в объект:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        exchange_rates: {
            BTC: JSON.parse('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
        }
    });
});
```

и получаю ошибку:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 1

Обычно на стороне браузера я делаю AJAX-запрос, но это сервер. Как можно получить доступ к JSON-файлу?

Comment: примерно так же:  сделай сначала асинхронный запрос. если ты тут новенький то поставь пакет node-fetch и используй его как в браузере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в этой строке `BTC: JSON.parse('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')`, вы пытаетесь распарсить не данные с удаленного ресурса, а строку `'https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker'`, [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) так не умеет, вам нужно предварительно получить данные, например при помощи [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (в вашем случае [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)), примерно так:

```js
// запрашиваем данные при помощи fetch
app.get('/', (req, res) => fetch('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker')
  .then((response) => response.json()) // парсим json
  .then((json) => res.render('index', { // отдаем ваш response
    exchange_rates: {
      BTC: json,
    },
  })));
```

Или тоже самое, но при помощи [async/await](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await):

```js
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await fetch('https://blockchain.info/ru/ticker');
  const json = await response.json();

  res.render('index', {
    exchange_rates: {
      BTC: json,
    },
  });
});
```